# Wrap a slide with a video popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, video, wistia

I'm using a slider for Wordpress titled 'UX Slider' by Flatsome themes. I have 3 image slides and 1 of those I want to link to a popup of a Wistia video when clicked.

This is the code that Wistia provides for the popup function:

```
<script src="//fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/####.jsonp" async></script>    
<script src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async>    </script>
<span class="wistia_embed wistia_async_#### popover=true popoverContent=link" style="display:inline">
<a href="#">Click Me</a></span>
```

I can't work out how to integrate this with the slider, though. This is the structure of the slider:

```
[ux_slider]
[ux_banner height="550px" bg="http://myurl.com/myimage.jpg" link="myurl.com"]

<p>Text here</p>

[/ux_banner]
[/ux_slider]
```

This is what I tried, but it doesn't work (no video shows at all):

```
 [ux_slider]
 [ux_banner height="550px" bg="http://www.myurl.com/myimage.jpg" link="" 
 <script src="//fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/####.jsonp" async></script>
 <script src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
 <span class="wistia_embed wistia_async_#### popover=true popoverAnimateThumbnail=true popoverContent=link" style="display:inline"></span> ]
 [/ux_banner]
 [/ux_slider]
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of different things could be the problem...

1. The plugin might be stripping away the `<script>` tags which would prevent your video from loading correctly.
2. The code you inserted might not be working correctly due to a typo.

To start, I would try using the popover demo code that Wistia has on their [help page](https://wistia.com/doc/embedding):

```
<script src="//fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/pukozq6xf0.jsonp" async></script>
<script src="//fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
<span class="wistia_embed wistia_async_pukozq6xf0 popover=true popoverAnimateThumbnail=true" style="display:inline-block;height:169px;width:300px">&nbsp;</span>
```

If that code works and the video shows, there might be a problem with your code that you originally tried to use.

If it still doesn't work, then it is probably not supported by the slider plugin you are using.

Comment: Thanks, that didn't work either, so it looks like the plugin just strips <script> tags.

Comment: @IVCatalina I use a plugin to create custom wordpress shortcodes in situations like this https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes-ui/